# CentOS 7 installer: blank screen

Tags: centos, centos7, kickstart

I am trying to figure out CentOS 7 unattended network (PXE) installations in my setup, but the installer always ends up running into a black screen without interaction options. This is being tried in a 64-bit VM (VMWare Workstation or Oracle VirtualBox).

The installer Kernel and initrd images have been sourced via `rsync -av` from here: *rsync.hrz.tu-chemnitz.de::ftp/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/images/pxeboot/* and were placed in the TFTP server's directory.

The installation seems to lift off normally, the Kernel boots up, initrd is loaded and startup scripts loading the kickstart file and the installer data off my repository server (via HTTP) have run more or less without errors:
[image: first stage]

At this stage, attempts to download *updates.img* and *product.img* are reported as failing as they are not present in the [repository I am using](http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/).

The install seems to proceed without errors:
[image: installer loading]

up to the point where it is mentioning that GNOME has started:
[image: GNOME started]

after which there is a screen mode switch and everything goes blank. Console switch attempts using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> <strike>do not work</strike> do work if I am persistent enough (it takes 2-3 hits to F3 to actually switch the console), where I can see that X has been started (by `/usr/sbin/gdm`) and is apparently hanging somewhere - the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file shows that VESA VBE drivers and input device drivers have been loaded successfully a suitable VESA mode has been chosen (0x144), yet it seems to stop there. From here, I can start `/sbin/anaconda` and the installer is running following the directives from the Kickstart config - if I have specified `text` in there, I can see the installer succeed and create a bootable system.

Things tried so far without success:

- Trying to kill X11 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> does not produce any result
- the `text`, `cmdline` and `skipx` [Kickstart installation options](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-options.html) as well as `nomodeset text` kernel parameters have been set to prevent the installer image from even starting X, but are not honored. The Kickstart installation options seem not to be even evaluated prior to Anaconda's start.
- playing around with `inst.xdriver=` [kernel boot options](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/master/docs/boot-options.txt) did not produce any different results
- I have tried VMWare Workstation as well as Oracle VirtualBox as the Hypervisor for my VM - to no avail
- I suspected a problem with my Kickstart script at which point I have exchanged my script initially [ripped off this sample](http://www.tecmint.com/multiple-centos-installations-using-kickstart/) by a ["minimal" one from here](https://www.centosblog.com/centos-7-minimal-kickstart-file/) merely replacing the `--url=` parameter's data by *http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/* (the installation mirror I want to use)
- I have tried using [another mirror](http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/) which changed nothing except for the download time of the 278M-sized installer image (presumably *LiveOS/squashfs.img*)

What is going wrong here and how would I fix my install?

Comment: Try  add `skipx` in Kickstart script

Comment: @FedericoSierra Tried that - X is starting and hanging as before.

Answer (score 2):

Edit you kernel bootup command line and add the following option: `nomodeset`
This should skip early framebuffer configuration and it will force X to common resolution, with little or no video acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

What is this about GNOME Display Manager? That shouldn't be present on an installation-only media. The fact that it is present makes me think you mistakenly downloaded a live media image. Go back to your mirror and get [the correct netinstall image](http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-NetInstall.iso).

Comment: I am not using an ISO, i am doing a network install with the sample kickstart script from [this site](http://www.tecmint.com/multiple-centos-installations-using-kickstart/) (Section 1 has the file content's listing) and `url` pointing to http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/. Honestly, I have no idea why GNOME is reported as loading although I explicitly have specified `text` in the kickstart file. But i do not know much about CentOS and Anaconda, so it might be reasonable after all.

Comment: Can you explain how you are booting, then? It should not be necessary to visit an external site to understand your question, even if the external site is helpful.

Comment: Gladly, but what exactly is it I would have to clarify? I already wrote that it is a PXE netinstall, specified the source of the binaries as well as the environment. I felt that pasting the Kickstart config file into the question would only add little value at the expense of the question becoming a wall of text.

Comment: Ah, I see you have already edited your question. Nevermind :)

Comment: Repeatedly even. It is a quirk that I have to take several iterations at most things I write before the text becomes comprehensible to others. Sorry for the confusion it created.